# Timetree: Use nodes for sorting

Tags: neo4j, cypher

having implemented a time tree in my Neo4J I ponder how I would be able to sort results of a query using the nodes of the timetree as each node standing alone is not sufficient for the query. In SQL I would have used maybe a CONCAT to generate a sort criteria but in Cypher I could use a hint.

Let's assume

```
MATCH (e:Event) --> (h:Hour)--(d:Day)--(m:Month) -- (y:Year)   
        RETURN  
                e.name 
        ORDER BY // here I would like to have an DESC or ASC order of the names depending on their relation to the timetree
```

How would I query so that all events are in the required order?

In addition, how would I query a timerange in that timetree e.g. from dd/mm/yy to dd/mm/yy?

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo4j will do auto-aggregation if your need is to aggregate by relationship type and you can order on the time property of your events nodes :

```
MATCH (n:Event)-[r]->(:Hour)
WITH type(r) AS rel, n
ORDER BY n.time DESC 
RETURN rel, collect(n) AS events
```

You can test the query here : http://console.neo4j.org/r/iqts8f

For querying in ranges, in the upcoming 2.3 range queries can use the index on the timestamp, however TimeTrees are often more complex than that, check here :

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. My issue was that I wanted to sort the nodes w/o them having an own timestamp but using the hook to the timetree. But I will then follow your advice and store the time again in the event node and sort by the node timestamp itsself rather than by the timetree. Good help, thank you.